# Using if else statements with User inputs

Tags: java

The if else statement won't work properly I've tried .equal ("1") but that doesn't work either

```
double TotalNum = NumOne + NumTwo; 

   System.out.println("Enter 1 to add or 2 to multiply another number ");
   double EquationType = input.nextDouble();

   if (EquationType == 1)){
       Total = Totalnum + 3.75;
  }
else
{
       Total = Totalnum * 1.25;
   }
System.out.prinln(Total);
```

Comment: Doesn't work mean ? Any error you getting? Where you declare Total ?

Comment: you have a extra ')' in your if statement.

Comment: You declare `TotalNum`, but using `Totalnum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use of undeclared variable. (TotalNum has capital N).

TotalNum not <strike>Totalnum</strike> in if-else